# Print the symbol table of an ELF file

Tags: c, elf, mmap, symbol-table

I have a program which uses the *mmap* system call:

```
map_start = mmap(0, fd_stat.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)
```

and a header variable:

```
header = (Elf32_Ehdr *) map_start;
```

How can I access the symbol table and print its whole content with the header variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get the section table by looking at the `e_shoff` field of the elf header:

```
sections = (Elf32_Shdr *)((char *)map_start + header->e_shoff);
```

You can now search throught the section table for the section with type `SHT_SYMBTAB`, which is the symbol table.

```
for (i = 0; i < header->e_shnum; i++)
    if (sections[i].sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
        symtab = (Elf32_Sym *)((char *)map_start + sections[i].sh_offset);
        break; }
```

Of course, you should also do lots of sanity checking in case your file is not an ELF file or has been corrupted in some way.

The [linux elf(5) manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/elf) has lots of info about the format.

Comment: ok,thank you, but now, how can i get the amount of the symbols in the symbols table?

Comment: `sh_size` tells you the size of the symbol table (in bytes); divide by `sh_entsize` (which should be the same as `sizeof(Elf32_Sym)`) to get the number of entries.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-0679/6mgfb878d/index.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libelf.h>
#include <gelf.h>

void
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Elf         *elf;
    Elf_Scn     *scn = NULL;
    GElf_Shdr   shdr;
    Elf_Data    *data;
    int         fd, ii, count;

    elf_version(EV_CURRENT);

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    elf = elf_begin(fd, ELF_C_READ, NULL);

    while ((scn = elf_nextscn(elf, scn)) != NULL) {
        gelf_getshdr(scn, &shdr);
        if (shdr.sh_type == SHT_SYMTAB) {
            /* found a symbol table, go print it. */
            break;
        }
    }

    data = elf_getdata(scn, NULL);
    count = shdr.sh_size / shdr.sh_entsize;

    /* print the symbol names */
    for (ii = 0; ii < count; ++ii) {
        GElf_Sym sym;
        gelf_getsym(data, ii, &sym);
        printf("%s\n", elf_strptr(elf, shdr.sh_link, sym.st_name));
    }
    elf_end(elf);
    close(fd);
}
```